# NSMutableArray changing old stored data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am parsing JSON and storing that data into `NSMutableArray` on my homepage. I want to access that data on my other page not after the another, so I am using Singleton Pattern for sharing common data in my homepage. I am storing that NSMutableArray data to Singleton file for common access. In second page i am  showing that data in `tableview`. There is one button which modifies the data but will not change original data i.e homepage `arraydata`. So I am storing that data into `clonearray` and updating that `clonearray`. But when I return back to homepage and in `ViewDidAppear` after placing breakpoint I am observing my original data is changed.

Please have a look on this issue and correct me where I am doing wrong with my code.

For more reference I added the project link please download and check this: [Project Link][1]

In this project I have created the 2 View Controllers , 1 model class, and one Singleton for common data across all file.

**View Controller:**

In this file I am parsing JSON and storing in NSMutableArray and also setting the same array data to Singleton file array for common access across all file.

**SecondViewController:**

In this file I am getting array data from Singleton file and storing in local array.

There is one button to modify data. In modify data function I am modifying the data and storing in the other array for common access (`clonearray`).

But when I return back to First View Controller and in `ViewDidAppear` after placing breakpoint, I am observing my original data is changed.
Please check, I don't want my original data to be changed. Please check and suggest me where I am doing wrong with my code.

Comment: You should post necessary  code in question instead of giving link for whole project!!

Comment: @KetanParmar sir i agree with you but the project whose reference is given by me is just a demo project. And its for good understanding what i am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem because all your property( `ViewController->shippingArray`, `SecondPageController->myshippingarray`, `PersonDtklSingleton->shippingAddress`) point to same array.

You can fix problem by clone array with [Deep Copies](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW3), to copy original to new array. Make sure all items in original array adopted `NSCopying`.

**SecondPageController**

```
@implementation SecondPageController
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myshippingarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // deep copy
    self.myshippingarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[PersonDtklSingleton sharedInstance]shippingAddress] copyItems:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
...
@end
```

**PersonModel**

```
@implementation PersonModel
@synthesize housernumber,resident,street,city,pincode,defaultAddress;

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    PersonModel *copyObj = [PersonModel new];
    copyObj.housernumber = [self.housernumber copyWithZone:zone];
    copyObj.resident = [self.resident copyWithZone:zone];
    copyObj.street = [self.street copyWithZone:zone];
    copyObj.city = [self.city copyWithZone:zone];
    copyObj.pincode = [self.pincode copyWithZone:zone];
    copyObj.defaultAddress = [self.defaultAddress copyWithZone:zone];
    return copyObj;
}

@end
```

Comment: sir first thanks for your reply. I am getting error in this line  [self setMyshippingarray:[[[PersonDtklSingleton sharedInstance]shippingAddress] copyItems:YES]];  that is "NO visible @interface for nsmutablearray declares the selector copyItems" Please correct me

Comment: @Sandeep function is NSArray initWithArray:copyItems:  not  copyItems:

Comment: @Sandeep look at my answer, I did call NSMutableArray initWithArray:copyItems: to deep copy your origin array. (note that NSMutableArray is sub class of NSArray so You can call all parent class function)

Comment: sir why u r using - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone  in model class. I never done this type of things with model class

Comment: @Sandeep read my document link about Deep Copies. It said that "If the objects do not adopt the NSCopying protocol, attempting to copy them in such a way results in a runtime error. ".  copyWithZone here just show the way to copy each item in Your array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122080/discussion-between-sandeep-and-a-bao).

Answer (score 0):

If I did't wrong when you update the data it change both of your data since it's referencing the same memory

you need to alloc a new memory and copy the data into a new array

like this

```
NSMutableArray *newArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:originalArray copyItems:YES];
```

You just update the newArray and the original one won't be affected